# PHP rand multiple math equation generator with overall results

Tags: php, forms, random, prompt

Basically I'm trying to display a maths equation with 2 random variables between 0,100.
I need to store 2 different variables which would be: amount of questions correct, and total questions answered.
Only by displaying one question at a time and on submit, prompting the user if they want to continue answering questions or to stop if continuing then refreshing the random values. upon stopping displaying the 3 stored variables.
in the format of " " correct and " " total questions answered.

```
<html>


    <head>

        <title></title>
    <?php
    function displayQuestion(){
    $firstVal = rand(0,100);
        $secondVal = rand(0,100);
        $valTotal = $firstVal + $secondVal;
    echo $firstVal . "+" . $secondVal . "=";
    }

    function answersCorrect(){
         $answer = 0;

         $firstVal = rand(0,100);
             $secondVal = rand(0,100);
             $valTotal = $firstVal + $secondVal;
         do {$valTotal;
         $answer ++;
         function displayAnswer() {
         if ($answer == $valTotal){
             $correct ++;
             $answer ++;        
         }
         echo "<p>You got {$correct} answers correct out of {$answer}.</p>";
     }
         }

         while ($answer == $valTotal);
         $correct = 0;


         }

             ?>

             <script>
             function query(){
             prompt("More questions (y/n)?");
             if (prompt != y || Y){
             <?php
             echo "answersCorrect();";
             ?>
             } else {
             function reloadPage(){
     location.reload(); 
     }
             } 
             }

             </script>
             </head>

             <body>
             <form action="calculate_randMath.php" method="post" id="mathsForm" name="answer">
             <p>Question: <?php echo displayQuestion(); ?> </p>
             <p>Your answer: <input type="text" name="answer" id="$answer"/></p>
             <p><input type="submit" value="answer" name="Submit" onClick="query()" /></p>
             </form>
             </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You cannot combine PHP and JavaScript like that. Why aren't you implementing all of the script in JS?

Comment: Well i'm trying to utilise php to do this and I'm not really sure the process of utilising a prompt in php, hence that was my best guess